# Position of figure in a new page

Tags: graphics, floats, vertical-alignment

Writing my thesis, I have to put an image in a new page, but it is always in the middle of the page, and I want it on the top. To insert the image I use

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\hspace*{-2.0cm} \includegraphics[scale=0.5] {img.png}
\caption{text}
\label{fig:text}
\end{figure}
```

using the `graphicx` package and `book` as `\documentclass`.

Answer (score 5):

If there is nothing follow the `figure` envrionment, the figure will appear in the middle of the page. Just try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\rule{4cm}{2cm} % dummy figure
\caption{DUMMY FIGURE}
\label{fig:text}
\end{figure}
\null % \hbox{}
\end{document}
```